# Pymongo define list as type of ObjectId for $in query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, fastapi

I have a list of ObjectIds which I want to pass into the following pymongo command to find the documents by their ObjectId

`ids = ['62b3221c2db07f9388aa61e9', '62b325f65402e5ceea9a3d4c', '62b48ccee6f77605c2783775']`

`list(dbusers.find({"_id" : {"$in": ids }}))`

However it expects them to be in the format
`ids = [ObjectId('62b3221c2db07f9388aa61e9'), ObjectId('62b325f65402e5ceea9a3d4c'), ObjectId('62b48ccee6f77605c2783775')]`

But I can't seem to get them in this format as they are in a list?

Comment: Does this help?  https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/objectid.html

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately not, it's the fact that it's a list rather just a single string I'm struggling with

Comment: `object_id_list = list(map(bson.objectid.ObjectId, ids))` should create a new list where each value has been wrapped in an `ObjectId` object, which is what I think @rickhg12hs suggested you do; you can then use this list with `"$in":` instead.

Comment: Spot on, I have posted what I used. Thank you rickhg12hs and @MatsLindh :) If you want to put an official answer I can mark it as answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the object id strings to proper `ObjectId` objects by giving the object id as a parameter when creating it (`ObjectId(<object_id>)`).

To convert your list to a list of `ObjectId` objects instead of a plain string list, you can use `map` which invokes a callable on each element in a list and returns an iterator - you can then exhaust this iterator and get a list back by giving it to `list`:

```py
from bson.objectId import ObjectId


object_id_list = list(map(ObjectId, ids))
found_users = list(dbusers.find({"_id": {"$in": object_id_list}}))
```

Since a class works as a callable to instantiate the class, you can give the class as the first argument to `map` and get objects created as that class back.